# Use tail recursion and match cases to traverse a binary tree in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, tail-recursion

I have a case class defined in scala as

```
case class Node(key: String, value: String, var left: Node, var right: Node)
```

and am trying to traverse it using tail recursion and a match case rather than loops and if statements. My current traversal method is as follows:

```
def find(key:String, tree:Node): Option[String] = {
    if(tree == null) {
        return None
    } else if (tree.key == key) {
        return Some(tree.value)
    }
    val checkLeft = find(key, tree.left)
    val checkRight = find(key, tree.right)
    if(checkLeft != None) {
        return checkLeft
    } else if(checkRight != None) {
        return checkRight
    }
    return None
}
```

How would I best go about creating a match with cases that uses tail recursion?

I currently have:

```
key match {
    case tree.key => Some(tree.value)
    case _ => find(key, tree.left)
}
```

but obviously this will not properly traverse my entire tree.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a binary search tree? Usually these have the property that everything on the left branch is less than the current key and everything on the right branch is greater than the key, so you only need to recurse on one branch. Otherwise, there's not much point in having a tree. Secondly, if expressions are totally fine in functional programming, but we tend to avoid explicit returns.

Comment: Just a hint, if you want to implement any tail-recursive keep this in mind, you may need to use accumulators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case class Node(key: String, value: String, var left: Node, var right: Node)

object Tree
{
    def find(key: String, tree: Node): Option[String] =
    {
        @tailrec
        def find_with_accumulator(key: String, node_list: List[Node]): Option[String] =
        {
            node_list match
            {
                case Nil => None
                case Node(k, value, left, right) :: rest =>
                    if (k == key) Some(value)
                    // .flatten removes all the None and unwraps the Options
                    else
                    {
                        find_with_accumulator(key, List(left, right).filter(_ != null) ++ rest)
                    }
            }
        }

        find_with_accumulator(key, List(tree))
    }
}
```

Adapted from https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/7984

I recommend changing the representation of the Tree as follows:

```
sealed abstract class AbstractNode

case class EmptyNode() extends AbstractNode

case class Node(key: String, value: String, left: AbstractNode, right: AbstractNode) extends AbstractNode

object Tree
{
    def find(key: String, tree: AbstractNode): Option[String] =
    {
        @tailrec
        def find_with_accumulator(key: String, node_list: List[AbstractNode]): Option[String] =
        {
            node_list match
            {
                case Nil => None
                case EmptyNode() :: rest => find_with_accumulator(key, rest)
                case Node(k, value, left, right) :: rest =>
                    if (k == key) Some(value)
                    else find_with_accumulator(key, left :: right :: rest)
            }
        }

        find_with_accumulator(key, List(tree))
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP is (unidiomatically) using `null` to signify the empty tree, based on this: `if(tree == null) { return None ...`

Comment: I agree it's not idiomatic, but trees already have a fairly large memory overhead and sometimes it can help reducing it (in this particular case it's probably avoidable with the use of a case object). Sometimes purity comes at a cost and it's a matter of trade-offs.

Comment: I agree that `EmptyNode` ought to be a `case object`.

Comment: @SethTisue I see. Thank you for the tip. I'm not completely familiar with Scala yet because it's only been a week since I read the Scala tutorial.